# Task-Cancellation after Task.WhenAny

Tags: c#

I have a method which spans multiple Tasks to do work in parallel - Their actual time to complete varies. When the first task finishes, the other work task(s) should be cancelled within the method like the code below:

```
static async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken){
    while(true) {
        using(CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
            Task workTask1 = Task.Delay(500, source.Token); // Some work
            Task workTask2 = Task.Delay(1500, source.Token); // Some other work

            await Task.WhenAny(workTask1, workTask2, Task.Delay(-1, cancelToken));

            if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;

            source.Cancel();

            // Do something with result ...
        }
    }
}
```

- Is there a better way to deal with / cancel the unfinished other work-tasks?
- I am also wondering about the costs of creating new `CancellationTokenSource` objects within every loop iteration.

Comment: I answered a similar concept here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60348001/5233410

Comment: How can we replicate this in order to help you?